# Email CSS for Mailbird

Tags: css, email, html-email

I have a mailer set up with inline CSS styling and it works fine for pretty much all email applications.

I am having issues with the Microsoft application Mailbird where I have received a report that the CSS is not showing at all.  Has anyone had any experience with Mailbird and know a way to get CSS to work with this app and apps like it?

I will include some of the email code here just to demonstrate the inline styling.

```
<html style="background: #191e26 !important; text-align: center !important;">

<body style="font-family: 'Noto Sans', Verdana; color: #fefefe; font-weight: 400; background: #191e26; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;">

<span style="font-family: 'Noto Sans', Verdana;">The big launch isn’t far away now, but we’ll let you know the minute we<br> take off so you can start making money.<br></span>
```

Comment: Your inline CSS is perfectly valid, so I can only assume that the problem is indeed with Mailbird. I don't have Mailbird myself, but just tested the code  through PHPMailer / Outlook, and that worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem went against common advice for emails.  I solved the issue by including CSS styling in the header alongside inline CSS.

Regards,

Ryan